# Problem while enter my password to open an editor

Tags: ssh, text-editor

I've installed ssh but I have a problem when I try to write my password.I get this message:

```
sudo] password for hduser: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for hduser: debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
```

Comment: Could you provide some more information? Are you using ssh to reach another machine where this is happening? What command did you enter to get the above?

Comment: yes I 'm using ssh and the command is **sudo nano ....**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Those aren't actually error messages. They are output because either ssh is using the -v command line option, or loglevel is defined in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. They can be ignored in the meantime.

If you just type your password as if the message weren't staring at you it should be possible to login if everything else is ok. It doesn't matter if you type over it.

If there is something else wrong it would be best to see the actual command you entered and all of the debug messages.